# Why the set of continuities of $f$ has measure zero in this problem?

Tags: measure-theory

This is the question and its answer:

> [image]

I can not understand the justification that is written in the solution of why III is right, could anyone clarify it for me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to show $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n dx=\int\lim_{n \to \infty}f_ndx=0$$You can appeal to Dominated convergence theorem to conclude $(iii)$. clearly $$f_n(x) \le 1 \text{ for all $x$ and $f_n(x) \to 0$ pointwise a.e}$$

By Dominated convergence theorem, you have the result.

Method-II: observe that $f$ which is the limit of $f_n$ is discontinuous only at $x=1$. Thus, the discontinuity has measure zero (since it is only a single point). Then $$0 \le \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 f_ndx \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 x^n dx=0$$
Moreover, letting $E=\{x \in [0,1]: f(x)=1\}$ (note that for $x \in E^c, f(x)=0$) , we have  $$\int_0^1 f dx=\int_E fdx+\int_{E^c}fdx=0$$

Comment: That does not answer the question, which was about the relevance of the fact that the set of discontinuity points of the limit function has measure $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I edited my answer,

Comment: How did you calculate $\int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x) dx$?

Comment: I showed. It is bounded above by $0$ and also bounded below by $0$